# Where should view/state logic live in Ember?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, frontend

I'm working on an Ember app and am having a hard time understanding where logic should go for a feature I'm building.  The feature is this, we're displaying a list of items whose title can be edited.  The desired effect is that the area where the text is displayed is by default a `<p>` tag, but when the edit button is clicked the title becomes a text field so the user can edit the title and save it.

This is the template currently for the title,

```
{{#if track.isBeingEdited}}
  {{ input value=track.title }}
{{else}}
  {{ track.title }}
{{/if}}
```

I'm thinking of having the button like this,

```
{{#if track.isBeingEdited}}
  <button {{action updateTitle}}>Save Title</button>
{{else}}
  <button {{action toggleEditState}}>Edit Title</button>
{{/if}}
```

Currently the model has `isBeingEdited` property that is set to false by default. I was thinking of having the actions be in the controller, which would change the value of the model's `isBeingEdited` property to true, or back to false and trigger a save for the new title.

I'm uncertain if `isBeingEdited` should be in the controller, which is an `Ember.ArrayController`.  Also, should the action of clicking on a button and toggling the `<p>` tag to a textarea be in the controller or should I create a component instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need an `itemController` ([see docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/#toc_item-controller))

then you can have your `isBeingEdited` on that item controller, and the actions to toggle between displaying and editing a single `track` would go there too.

The actions to save the model would go on the `route`